# Correct way to use an array to access multiple arrays of different length in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have several two dimensional arrays of various, differing lengths:

```
int Array_A[][2] = {{...}, {...}, {...}, ...};
int Array_B[][2] = {{...}, {...}, ...};
int Array_C[][2] = {{...}, ...};
```

I need another array which allows me to access these arrays:

```
??? Full_Array[] = {Array_A, Array_B, Array_C};
```

What is the correct type of `???` that I should use? I tried `uint**` and `uint*` but neither works.

If it's not doable, **suppose I am not allowed to change the definition** of `Array_A`, `Array_B`, ... What is a good way to define `Full_Array`?

Comment: You're trying to create an array of arrays of arrays, so...

Comment: No, they're trying to create an array of pointers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it's not a 3-dimension array. The original 2-dimension array can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: I think the question should be rephrased to actually ask what you mean: You don't want the addresses of those arrays, you want access to their elements and thus need an array of pointers to the (first) elements of those arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array_A`, `Array_B`, and `Array_C` are all arrays of arrays of 2 `int`s, so they can all undergo the array-to-pointer conversion *at the top level* into pointer to array of 2 `int`s.

So `Full_Array` needs to be an array of pointers to arrays of 2 `int`s. The declaration can be written:

```
int (*FullArray[])[2] = {Array_A, Array_B, Array_C};
```

Note that there is no way to tell what the lengths of the subarrays are, unless you have sentinel values.

Comment: While this is a useful question in general terms (so I won't mark it down) it doesn't actually answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays `Array_A`, `Array_B`, and `Array_C` are of the same size, you can create pointers to them using the `&` operator and store them in an array. If they are of different sizes, the `&` operator will create different pointer types and you won't be able to store them in the pointer array.

```
int Array_A[3][2] = { ... };
int Array_B[3][2] = { ... };
int Array_C[3][2] = { ... };

typedef int (*PtrType)[3][2];
PtrType Full_Array[] = {&Array_A, &Array_B, &Array_C};
```

The following will be an error.

```
int Array_A[][2] = { {}, {}, {} }; // Implied dimensions [3][2]
int Array_B[][2] = { {}, {} };     // Implied dimensions [2][2]
int Array_C[][2] = { {}, {}, {} }; // Implied dimensions [3][2]

typedef int (*PtrType)[3][2];
PtrType Full_Array[] = {&Array_A, &Array_B, &Array_C};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already posted answers, you might want to consider using [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to automatically deduce the type:

```
using PtrToArrayElem =
    decltype(&(Array_A[0]));                      // C++11, or
//  std::decay_t<decltype(Array_A)>;              // C++14 alternative, or
//  typename std::decay<decltype(Array_A)>::type; // C++11 version of above
PtrToArrayElem arrayOfPtrsToFirstElements[] = {Array_A, Array_B, Array_C};
```

The benefit is that if you ever change the type of one of the arrays, then you don't need to change the code here. Just make sure to keep the rest of the code (accessing the array of pointers) generic, too.

---

Of course this also works if you rather want to store addresses to the arrays themselves, which will only work if they're of the same size:

```
using PtrToArray = decltype(&Array_A);
PtrToArray arrayOfPtrToArray[] = {&Array_A, &Array_B, &Array_C};
```

---

*Note: Variable names are chosen for descriptive purposes of this answer. You should of course use meaningful names.*

Comment: This won't work because each of the three arrays can have a different length.

Comment: @Brian This won't work **if** the arrays have different lengths. Quoting the question: "I need another array which stores the *addresses of these arrays*" This is actually the "correct" answer. But, of course, using array-to-pointer conversion might make more sense to the OP. Doesn't change the point of my answer though: use `decltype` if sensible

Comment: I disagree, Daniel.   The OP stated in the first line that the arrays are of different lengths.   In other words, the first dimension of `Array_A`, `Array_B`, and `Array_C` are potentially different.  And if that is the case, they are of different types, so pointers to them are of different types.

Comment: @Peter Hm, I see. I didn't really noticed that line. The main point of my answer remains still unchanged, though. I edited it to shift the focus on handling arrays of different lengths, though.

Comment: Or `using PtrToArrayElem = std::decay_t(decltype(Array_A));`

Comment: @aschepler Indeed, added (with correct syntax and C++14 "warning", though).